# Sequelize simple inner join

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models, `policyTable` and `policy_rule` defined as below. There is a column called `policy_id` in `policy_rule` which is a foreign key and references to `id` column in `policyTable`. The `policy_rule` can have multiple `policyTable`, i.e there is a 1:N relationship.

```
var policyTable = dbController.db.define('policyTable', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    't': {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        unique: true
    },
    'name': {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    src: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
}, {
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'zo_policy',
});

var policy_rule = dbController.db.define('policy_rule', {
    policy_id: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        references: {
            model: policyTable,
            key: 'id'
        },
        onUpdate: 'cascade',
        onDelete: 'cascade'
    },
    agent_id: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
    },
    enabled: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    }
}, {
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'zo_policy_rule',
});
```

Now I want to join these two models and get all columns of both of them. How can I do that? I tried the below code but it says

> Error: policy_rule is not associated to policyTable!

```
function getAllPolicies() {
    return policyTable.findAndCountAll({
        include: [{
            model: policy_rule
            }]
    }).then(function (users) {
        console.log(users);
        data.count = users.count;
        data.users = users.rows;
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though your associations are defined at the database level, and you indicate this in your column definitions, to use sequelize's `include` feature, you still need to explicitly define your associations between models, too.

Here's the relevant section in the doco: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongsto
and 
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#1m

In your case, it'll mean adjusting your code to something along the lines of below - note the new `classMethods` section in each model definition:

```
var policyTable = dbController.db.define('policyTable', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    't': {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        unique: true
    },
    'name': {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    src: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
}, {
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'zo_policy',
    classMethods: {
      associate(models) {
        this.hasMany(models.policy_rule, {foreignKey: 'policy_id'})
      }
    }
});

var policy_rule = dbController.db.define('policy_rule', {
    policy_id: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        references: {
            model: policyTable,
            key: 'id'
        },
        onUpdate: 'cascade',
        onDelete: 'cascade'
    },
    agent_id: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
    },
    enabled: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    }
}, {
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'zo_policy_rule',
    classMethods: {
      associate(models) {
        this.belongsTo(models.policyTable, {foreignKey: 'policy_id'})
      }
    }
});
```